# Entity Framework 6 and Geography data STContains

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, geospatial, sqlgeography

I've included `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` to enable the geography and geometry types in Entity Framework, but I don't see any functions equivalent to `STContains()`.

I need to make a query to retrieve the geography that contains a point

In SQL I wrote like this:

```
SELECT adm1code, adm1name 
FROM Adm2GeoBoundaries
WHERE Coords.STContains(geography::Parse('POINT(-121.703796 46.893985)'));
```

in LINQ I expect to have something like

```
using (GeoEntities db = new GeoEntities ())
{
    DbGeography location = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-121.703796 46.893985)");
    var admin = from a in db.Adm2GeoBoundaries
                where a.Coords.STContains(location)
                select a;
}
```

but `a.Coords.STContains(location)` throws an error

> STContains method doesn't exist

Comment: have you tried `.Contains()` ?

Comment: @devlincarnate sure, there isn't...

Comment: Would you be willing to put that into a Stored Procedure, and then call it from your EF?

Comment: @tgolisch we can't use stored procedures in this project. And for consistency in the architecture design, I'd like to avoid workarounds. It sounds so crazy they have forgotten to implement the STContains function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code for EF6 [Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/), the `STContains` seems to be implemented as Contains in EF6.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlSpatialServices.cs

[image]

Looking at the `SqlTypesAssembly.cs` you should be able see it should invoke the `STContains` method.

[image]